# How do recovery softwares access the mft table directly?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs-mft

Im curious how do recovery softwares open the Master File Table. Like do they do api calls ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no API calls to read an MFT. But you can find the cluster where the Mft is stored and read its content by traversing through disk.